# how do I properly isolate the containers with firewalld with iptables=false?

Tags: firewalld, nftables

I do not want the docker modify my iptables/nftables on fly so I decided to use iptables=false.
I then follow the suggestion [here](https://dev.to/soerenmetje/how-to-secure-a-docker-host-using-firewalld-2joo) to enable the outbound internet connection inside the containers.

However, I soon discovered there is no default rule to block inter-container or even inter-bridge communication at all.
This makes the security in illusion: the compromised container in untrusted zone can simple use trusted containers in trusted zone as jump to get into my host.

For example, I have br1, br2, br3. br1 and br2 are in zone1 (full default setting), br3 are in zone2 also full default setting.

```
zone1
  target: default                                      
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br1 br2                                                
  sources:                     
  services: ssh                             
  ports:                                  
  protocols:                        
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

zone2
  target: default                                      
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br3
  sources:                     
  services: ssh                             
  ports:                                  
  protocols:                        
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I would expect at least br3 cannot initiate connection to br1/br2.
So I did `nc -lk -p 12345 -e /usr/bin/cat` in br1.
Then I try nc to communicate with it. surprisingly there is no blockage at all.
It can successfully open the port and send message.

why is that?
I thought container3-->| br3 --> port on the host
so by default everything except ssh is blocked here

then how exactly does it connect to container1?
maybe container3-->| br3 --> br1|--> container1

When container3 and container1 are the real machine and br3 and br1 are the real interface. It looks like this actually require to setup some forwarding rules or inter-zone policy to allow the traffic go through.
Moreover, at least container3-->| br3 should be blocked, thus even the forwarding rules are set if I do not open the ports on br3, it will not be able to reach the other side?

But it seems like in the container/bridge situation this is not true. There is no blockage at all.

I wonder what is the canonical way 1. to prevent the containers attach to the bridges in different zone to communicate. 2. to prevent the inter-container-connect inside a same zone.

Is this completely out of the concept of firewalld? So it can only be achieved with raw nft calls or iptables-nft calls? The direct rule is almost the same as the bear call of nft, since there is no per-zone or inter-zone concept can be used in there at all.

ok, it probably because of br_netfilter is not loaded and proper isolation rule is not inserted. I guess it is way more complicated than I expected. The firewalld is not the way to go maybe